# Download Manager: How to re-construct chunks fetched by multiple connections

Tags: python, urllib2, connection, chunks

so i am developing my own download manager for educational purpose. I have multiple connections/threads downloading a file, each connection works on a particular range of the file. Now after they have all fetched their chunks, i dont exact  know how to i bring this chunks together to re-make the original file.

What i did:

First, i created a temporary file in 'wb' mode, and allowed each connections/threads to dump their chunks. But everytime a connection does this, it overwrites previously saved chunks. I figured this was because i used the 'wb' file descriptor. I changed it to 'ab', but i can no longer perform seek() operations

What i am looking for:

I need an elegant way of re-packaging this chunk to the original file. I would like to know how other download managers do it.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing it just fine: `seek()` and `write()`. That should work!

Now, if you want a cleaner structure, without so many threads moving their hands all over a file, you might want to consider having downloader threads and a disk-writing thread. This last one may just sleep until woken by one of the others, write some kb to disk, and go back to sleep.

Comment: Thanks alot. No wonder the pc usage stays at 100%, i think this is because the threads constantly acquires the lock and saves every 20KB it downloads. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to write chunks it different temporary files and then join them in the original order. If you open one file for all the threads, you should make the access to it sequential to preserve to correct order of data, which discards thread usage since a thread should wait for the previous one. BTW, you should open files in `wb` mode.

Comment: Thanks for this. Especially the thread usage part. The threads wait for the lock to be released making the app quite slow. Thanks